# Windows doesn't recognize SSD

Tags: windows, ssd, motherboard

I have a ASUS P5N-D motherboard and an SSD Disc OCZ Vector.I can see the SSD disc in BIOS, but Windows doesn't seem to recognize it. Why isn't Windows recognizing it?

Comment: Do you have the SSD formatted? And can you see it in Disk Management?

Comment: No I cant only in BIOS. Asus said: This sounds as a compability issue, please note that all ssd drives needs to be 
run in AHCI mode to be able to use it fully and in some cases if is not run in AHCI it doesnt work at all
So does that mean that there is none SSD disk I can use witm my motherboard ASUS P5N-D?

Answer (score 0):

Start by trying other SATA and power cables, other SATA ports and try the SSD on another computer to narrow things down to either the SSD or the motherboard/settings.

If you get the SSD to be recognized on another computer (internally or externally) get a diagnostic tool from the manufacturer and see if the SSD passes all tests. Checking if it has the latest firmware is also a good idea. This should completely rule out the SSD as the potential cause of the issue.

On the system's side, make sure the BIOS, OS and all drivers have their latest updates installed. 
Check if you are using UEFI, IDE/AHCI/RAID options and under what settings are your other drives operating (MBR/GPT, etc.).

If you have a OS installation disk or a bootable thumb drive with either a bootable OS or a bootable installer of a OS try unplugging the rest of the storage drives and leave only the SSD and see if it's recognized.

Check again if the device is visible in [Device Manager](http://products.wdc.com/support/kb.ashx?id=cT2wiq) or [Disk Management](http://products.wdc.com/support/kb.ashx?id=jqJZFC) after you check all your settings and for updates.

Try connecting the drive to the same PC externally (via a SATA to USB calbe (the SSD doesn't need external power), Dock station or a simple external enclosure) and see if the system recognizes it this way.